# Android Ndk compilation issue on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk

While compiling my Native C file on Mac OS Ver 10.6.8 -- I am getting the following error

```
VibhasChandra:com.htp.DrivingRange vibhasc$ /Users/vibhasc/Desktop/myeclipse/android-ndk-r8c/ndk-build 
SharedLibrary  : libndk1.so
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _memmem**

Referenced from: /Users/vibhasc/Desktop/myeclipse/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _memmem**

Referenced from: /Users/vibhasc/Desktop/myeclipse/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

clang: error: unable to execute command: Trace/BPT trap
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** ****[obj/local/armeabi/libndk1.so] Error 254
```

I know this will work easily on a linux machine but in Mac its giving errors...how to fix this..??
How to create the dyLib file in

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported by several people who have been trying to use R8C on OS X. See e.g. [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/2L0TyNaiywA) on the android-ndk list.

The proposed workaround is as follows:

> I was able to come up with a possible workaround for this particular problem. I made a new shared library that implements memmem(). I use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES to get the memmem.dylib to load into the process and DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 to let ld find _memmem inside memmem.dylib instead of libSystem.B.dylib where it wants to look for it. I'm not sure if any other symbols need the same treatment.

I'm afraid it doesn't contain any more detail than that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the newer version of the Android NDK, Revision 8d (December 2012) i.e. android-ndk-r8d release.

For your reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Revisions

Fix info is here:

> Fixed a linker failure with the NDK 8c release for Mac OS X 10.6.x
>   that produced the following error:
>
> > dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _memmem Referenced
> >     from: ...../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld Expected in:
> >     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> This problem was caused by building on Mac OS X 10.7, which produced
>   binaries that were not compatible with Mac OS 10.6.x and the NDK.

Have downloaded and tried with the newer NDK. Works fine.